# solr: What is the memory limit for loading data to solr?

Tags: search, solr, search-engine

What is the memory limit for loading data into solr?
I tried loading a 1.1Gigabyte file and ended up with a `500 Server error`.
Digging the log file showed me this:

```
ERROR - 2013-11-25 17:26:46.481; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; null:java.lang.IllegalStateException: this writer hit an OutOfMemoryError; cannot commit
```

Answer (score 2):

Solr runs on JVM, so the java heap space should be [large enough to avoid OutOfMemoryException](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#How_much_heap_space_do_I_need.3F). There are obvious downside to increasing the Heap Space to a value too big, which is pointed out in the reference.

I would revisit the strategy of uploading large files, if I were you, and either do a batch processing by [splitting the files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452626/326543) or consider doing incremental updates (depending on your use case).